Meaning of 重ねる here
There is one sentence I have hard time understanding from this essay:

また、キラ・ヤマトはスーパーコーディネイターとして数多の犠牲の上に生み出された自身の出自と重ね「望む力を全て得ようと遺伝子にまで手を伸ばしてきたコーディネイターの世界の究極」である、漫画『THE EDGE』内では「遺伝子で職業が決まるなら、より職業の適性の高い優れた人間を狙って製造する方向へと加速する」＝「人間を工業製品やパーツ同等として扱う様になる」「より社会的に優遇される職（医者や政治家など）への適性をコーディネイトする様になる」と危惧し、「未来を作るのは運命（遺伝子の適性）じゃない」「夢（願い・希望・欲望）を抱けないのは嫌だ」と反感を示した。

I need help deciphering the meaning of the bold part. In particular, I am not sure about the function of と before 重ね and what 重ね means exactly. I think it means "to stack up his own origins, which is produced on lots of sacrifices"? I can't make sense of this translation.

It usually takes the form AとBを重ねる or something similar. Considering it's a wiki, I wonder if someone might have removed a word or two accidentally.

重ねる means "to overlap (in thought)" rather than "to stack". The object of 重ねる is omitted, but it's Destiny Plan. The sentence suggests that the Plan and his background have a lot in common.

キラ・ヤマトはスーパーコーディネイターとして数多の犠牲の上に生み出された自身の出自と重ね...
Kira Yamato paralleled/compared [Destiny Plan] with his own origins as a super coordinator created at the cost of many sacrifices, and...

